# How to draw on HTML5 canvas without putImageData()?

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, kineticjs

I found this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17565 and it seems that it is not going to get solved soon, so I would like to know, how can I draw on canvas without using the putImageData()?

```
var imgCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = imgCanvas.getContext("2d");
var imageObj.src = 'img/someImage.png';
imageObj.onload = function(){

ctx.draw(imageObj,0,0);
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,30,30);
var data = imageData.data;          
for(var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {                                 
    data[i]+=20;//red   
    data[i+1]-=20;//green
    data[i+2]-=20;//blue
    data[i+3]=0; //alpha, но я не трогаю этого параметра             
}
ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
}
```

For instance, in normal browsers, the result of changing a pixel rgba=[100,100,100,200] with the above script should be rgba=[120,80,80,200], but on android's 4.2 default browser the result is not the expected, is something weird like rgba=[153,102,102,200]. Anyway, the point is that there is an issue and I would like to know, how can I change one image's rgba parameters without using the putImageData() method?. If there is not a way with canvas, I would like to know, how can solve this another way? I need to change the image color dinamically, and I need this to work on android (I am using phonegap and the result is the same as in the default android browser). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the full image color by a factor (for example, add 10 to r, 30 to g and 4 to b), you could use globalComposite operations:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing

Check 'lighter' and 'darker' ops.

If you want to set a different color / factor to each pixel, i think that putImageData is the way to go...

Hope it helps.